Understanding the Schrodinger flow——Symplectic Banach manifold
This question was posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925369/understanding-the-schrodinger-flow-symplectic-banach-manifold  but recieve nothing. I really want to know the something about Schrodinger flow but with poor geometric backgrand, and I just studied Riemannian geometry several years ago but it seems that Riemannian geometry is not enough for understanding this question.
When I reading the paper "Schrodinger flow of maps into symplectic manifolds,1998", I'm confused by the concept symplectic Banach manifold.
For the readers' convenient, I carry the material in the paper to here:
Let $(N,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and let $J$ be an almost complex structure on N such that $$h(\cdot,\cdot):=\omega(\cdot,J\cdot)$$ be the Riemannian metric. It is well known that any smooth function $f$ on $N$ corresponds to a Hamiltonian vector field $V_f$, which is given by the relation$$df(v)=\omega(v,V_f).$$ From $h(\cdot,\cdot):=\omega(\cdot,J\cdot)$  one easily derives $$V_f=J{\rm grad} f,$$ where ${\rm grad} f$ denotes the gradient of $f$ with respect to the metric $h$. The flow is defined by ode$$\dot{u}=J(u){\rm grad}f(u)$$ is called the Hamilton flow of Hamiltonian function $f$.
It is natural to generalize the notion of Hamiltonian flow to an infinite-dimensional setting.
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $X=C^k(M,N)(k\geq1)$. We may consider $X$ as a symplectic Banach manifold with the symplectic form $\Omega$ defined by $$\Omega(u)(v,w)=\int_{M}\omega(u)(v,w)dv_{g},\forall u\in X,\forall v,w\in T_{u}X$$
Similarly, we define an inner product on the tangent bundle $TX$ by
$$\langle v,w\rangle_{u}=\int_{M}h(u)(v,w)dv_{g},\forall u\in X,\forall v,w\in T_{u}X$$
For $F\in C^1(X,\mathbb{R})$ is any functional, we let $T_{F}$ be the gradient of $F$ with respect to the above inner product, i.e.$$dF(u)(v)=\langle T_{F}(u),v\rangle$$Then one can show that the corresponding Hamiltonian vector field$V_F$ (satisfying$$dF(u)(v) 
= Q(u)(v,V_F(u))$$ has the expression
$$V_F(u) = J(u)T_F(u)$$
Here my question is why $X$ is a symplectic Banach manifold? I'm not familiar with infinite dimensional geometry. Isn't $X$ a flat Banach space? why we call it Banach manifold, in addition, they add the term sympletic Banach manifold , and at the beginning of the paragraph, the symplectic form is defined for finite dimensional symplectic form, but here it seems that $\omega(u)$ is defined on infinite dimensional... The following about metric $h$ is similar, I don not know if it is defined on finite dimensional space nor infinite?
Any hints are wellcome, thanks ahead!

You already got a pretty good answer, but I just want to mention quickly that X is not a "flat Banach space": when $N$ is a manifold there is no linear structure on $C^k(M,N)$ since you cannot add two points in $N$.

@WillieWong,Wake-up call explanation! Thank you!

If you want to know why $X=C^k(M,N)$ is a Banach manifold, see the paper 'Geometry of manifolds of maps' by Eliasson. If you want to know more about Banach manifolds in general and how (symplectic) forms are defined on them see 'Differential and Riemannian Manifolds' by Lang. A more gentle introduction to these topics is 'Introduction to Global Analysis' by Moore, which is partly available here.
